# Impersonation in WCF service hosted in Claims-authenticated SharePoint 2010

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wif, claims

I have a WCF service which uses wsHttpBinding with message security and windows authentication.

A console application service client is able to call the service, and I can see that both the ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity and Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity represent the right user.

The currentprincipal is a IClaimsIdentity, as expected.

The problem occurs when I try to open a SharePoint web: I get an access denied error suggesting that the impersonated identity can't be passed to the database or sharepoint server. This is all with in the same machine though, so there shouldn't be any double-hop authentication issues.

Is this not the correct way of doing headless authentication against a service hosted in a claims application?

Comment: How do you open the SP Web ? Do you use the constructor overload that accepts a SPUserToken ?

Comment: I've tried that as well. It seems my IClaimsIdentity is a Microsoft.IdentityModel.WindowsClaimsIdentity, rather than a Microsoft.IdentityModel.ClaimsIdentity. SharePoint's SPUserToken contructor throws an exception if the IClaimsIdentity object is anything but a ClaimsIdentity.

Comment: I guess you need to transform the claims. Have you tried to instantiate a ClaimsIdentity from a WindowsClaimsIdentity ?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work. I've also tried removing the federation extensions from the endpoint configuration, and use plain windows authentication against the service. That brings me back to the permission denied error. Trying to instantiate a spusertoken from a claimsidentity, given a windowsidentity as input, also fails.

Comment: If you're only considering plain windows authentication, have you configured impersonation on the WCF side (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

I currently have WCF services that are deployed in a claims-enabled SharePoint 2010 site. The WCF services are nothing fancy and I use the provided Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory as the WCF service factory. Thus, I'm using the out-of-the-box BasicHttpBinding provided through the factory.

My client app.config looks as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyServices" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="200524288" maxBufferPoolSize="200524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="200524288"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/_vti_bin/MyServices/MyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyServices"
        contract="ServiceClient.MyService.IMyService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When looking at my Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity, it's correct. It is a ClaimsIdentity with my currently executing user. I can then simply open a new SPSite instance without having to create or utilize an SPUserToken.

One key thing to note: I don't impersonate my identity before connecting to the WCF service. If this is what you're doing, it's not likely to work unless your SharePoint server has an established trust with your claims provider.